# How to handle exception in another project using RestTemplate

Tags: exception, spring-data-jpa

In following code I am trying to find out department table data according to nDeptId. If that object is null I am throwing `DataRetrievalFailureException`. How to handle this exception in another spring project using `RestTemplate`

```
  Department deptmentObj = new Department();
                deptmentObj = depRepo.findByNDeptId(accountObj.nDeptId);

                if (deptmentObj == null) {
                    throw new DataRetrievalFailureException("DataRetrievalFailureException for ndeptid");
                }
    }
```

can any one tell me what I need to change?